# JSON not returning child object details for same type

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I have a JPA entity which is returned as a ResponseEntity from a REST end point. The end point returns a collection of that entity - Code below

```
public ResponseEntity<Collection<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
Collection<Employee> returnedEmployees = employeeService.findAll();  
return new ResponseEntity<>(returnedEmployees, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

`Employee` entity has a `modifiedByUser` property which is of type `User`.

When I invoke the endpoint it returns the collection just fine but the only problem is only the first element in the collection returns the details about the `modifiedByUser`, rest of the element just maps an id to it.

sample response

```
[
{
"employeeId" : 1,
"firstName" : "John",
"lastName" : "Doe",
"modifiedByUser" : {
   "userId" : 1,
   "firstName" : "Admin"
},

{
"employeeId" : 2,
"firstName" : "Jane",
"lastName" : "Doe",
"modifiedByUser" : 1
}
]
```

I want `modifiedByUser` property in the second element to also show full details.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Audited
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotAudited
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User modifiedByUser;

// getters and setters
```

User.java

```
    @Entity
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "userId")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -74583759743985L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private int userId;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
// getters and setters
```

Comment: give some more details like repository methods and Database?

Comment: I am using spring data jpa repository - `EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>`. Database is MySQL

Comment: are you using any Relationship between modifiedByUser Object and Employee, like OneToOne?

Comment: Can u share your Employee entity class? most probably some JPA configuration that you have might be preventing to query the child relations

Comment: Added Employee and User class.

Comment: Your annotation JsonIdentityInfo may be causing this behavior. Try removing it?

Comment: Yes, it did solved the problem. Thanks @MetroidFan2002

Comment: No problem. Just be aware that without something like that Json deserialization will want the full user object as well.

Comment: show your DAO method/class